# Multiples of a combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

If we look at the series $\{{2n \choose n}\}_{n\geq 1}$, is there a constant $k$, where $k$ is even, s.t. for every $n\geq 1$, there exists some $m>n$ s.t.

$$\frac{{2m\choose m}}{{2n\choose n}}=k$$

My attempt: I was looking at Stirlings's approximation for a factorial $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$, so that gives ${2n \choose n}\sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Because of the $\sqrt{n}$ term in the denominator, I am not sure if such a constant $k$ exists?

Comment: Stirling is only approximate, so why would it show what you want, which is exact?

Comment: @coffeemath It probably doesn't but that was just my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was true, then there would exist $m_1$ and $m_2$ for which
$$
\frac{\binom{2m_1}{m_1}}{\binom{2}1}=\frac{\binom{2m_2}{m_2}}{\binom42}=k
$$
so that
$$
\frac{\binom{2m_2}{m_2}}{\binom{2m_1}{m_1}}=3.
$$
However, letting $a_n=\binom{2n}{n}$, the pariwise ratios $a_{m}/a_n$  are always more than $3$ when $m>n\ge 1$ (except when $m=2,n=1$). I am sure you can prove this analytically; intuitively, the smallest ratios are $a_{n+1}/a_n$, and in the limit this ratio approaches $4$.